# Does a Thread launched by Activity continue running once the device goes to sleep?

Tags: android, multithreading

This is somewhat similar to [App seems to stop working when the screen goes to sleep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5345344/app-seems-to-stop-working-when-the-screen-goes-to-sleep) however they discuss an AsyncTask while in my situation it is a plain Thread.

So let's say an activity starts a Thread, and then the phone goes to sleep, does the thread continue execution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not unless you have a [wakelock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html). (It does continue to run if your activity goes to the background, but might be killed at any time the foreground activity requires more resources.)