# What should I do when the android activity is interrupted?

Tags: android

I currently have a program where a user fills information out and sends it to a server. It then downloads a one to two MB file to device. I have it setup so the phone does not sleep when it is downloading the file, but it is interrupted when the user manually presses the sleep button or a text comes in to the phone. What would be the best solution to this? Should I create a service or is there someway to tell the activity to keep downloading in the onPause method?

Comment: Try looking at `IntentService` http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html

Comment: Have you tried wake_lock? http://stackoverflow.com/a/5345385/1426565

Answer (score 1):

won't it be better to download in the background using an android service and posting an android notification when it will be done?