# What is efficient among, waiting on condition_variable vs waiting on socket?

Tags: c++, performance, c++11, select, condition-variable

Suppose, if we have a choice to make between `wait_until` and `select(timveval)`, then which one is better? Do anyone has performance benefit over the other or is it implementation defined?

---

<sub>**Why this question?**</sub>
<sub>Was trying to solve this problem: [Android: C++ thread not waking up if screen-locked or in background. Works fine when app is in use](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40865524/514235)</sub>
<sub>To summarise, a thread containing `std::condition_variable::wait_until` is Not waking up when an Android device is locked. This is happening probably due to CPU going for sleep. If I replace it with `socket` > `select` > `timeval (wait)`, as mentioned in [select man page](http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman2/select.2.html), then the situation is little better, where the thread wakes up "sometimes". As of now, none of them solve the problem.</sub>

Comment: Did you try [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) which might be marginally better than `select` ? See also [time(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/time.7.html)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, No I haven't tried `poll()` before. Do you have any reference on it; i.e. in what situations will it be better than `select()`? For now I have to deal with only 1 or 2 sockets at a time. What is the link to `time(7)` regarding, is it another alternative?

Comment: Perhaps consider some `timerfd_create` to be used in conjunction with `poll` (which is probably slightly faster than `select`, notably when you have many file descriptors, or one with some large number). But YMMV and you need to benchmark.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Using `poll` instead of select would have no major advantage in his case, since he is dealing with just 2 sockets.

Comment: I would prefer `wait_until` over `select` if I have to block my thread because,  use of `condition_variable` in the code looks more contextually applicable.