# Slow down the auto-off process of the android app after turning off the screen

Tags: android

I created a music app on the android platform but when I let it run for a few minutes when the screen turned off, the app turned off and didn't play the music anymore. So how do I extend the time the application runs when the screen is turned off?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [App seems to stop working when the screen goes to sleep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5345344/app-seems-to-stop-working-when-the-screen-goes-to-sleep)

Comment: @mohit You link to question asked in 2011...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming that you are running the `Service` to play music in the background. So, when OS thinks that the mobile device has to reduce the battery consumption, it just kills your `service` sometime after it was run.

Now, what you can do to avoid this, is running that in **foreground** instead. Because then that service is kind of marked as useful by the user so that doesn't get killed unless the user themselves do that.

Find out more about **How to set a Service to run in foreground** [here in the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services#Foreground)

The above link clearly mentions:

> a music player that plays music from a service should be set to run in the foreground

But keep in mind that any service to accomplish any task should run in the foreground only if the user is aware that the task is being accomplished.

> You should only use a foreground service when your app needs to perform a task that is noticeable by the user even when they're not directly interacting with the app.

And for that reason, you must show a notification mentioning that *this* service is being run in the foreground, to accomplish *this* task, so that the user can be in knowledge of that.

> A foreground service must provide a notification for the status bar, which is placed under the *Ongoing* heading. This means that the notification cannot be dismissed unless the service is either stopped or removed from the foreground.